# Struggling with EXC_BAD_ACCESS and UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, memory-management, exc-bad-access

I'm tearing my hair out here. My RootViewController loads an array of strings from a plist. When it loads it works fine. I then tap on a row which sends it to a new view controller. If I go back, the table still works fine, so I tap on another row which works as expected. Now if I go back and scroll I get a crash pointing at `cell.textLabel.text = [self.faceCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Abridged source code below:

```
// RootViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class DetailViewController;

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *faceCategories;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *faceCategories;
@end
```

RootViewController implementation
    // RootViewController.m

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@synthesize faceCategories;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; 

    // Init array
    if (self.faceCategories == nil) {
        NSLog(@"NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL");
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //Create a list of paths.
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get a path to your documents directory from the list.
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"faceCategories.plist"]; //Create a full file path.

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) //Check if file exists.

        {
            NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"faceCategories" ofType:@"plist"]; //Get a path to your plist created before in bundle directory (by Xcode).
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error]; //Copy this plist to your documents directory.
        }
        // Zombies percentages after
        NSMutableArray *fileContents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path]; // 55.6%
        self.faceCategories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:fileContents copyItems:YES]; // 33.3%
        [fileContents release]; // 11.1%

    }
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    /////////////////////////////
    // CRASH HERE only after I return to this view controller a couple of times
    // If I enable breakpoints and add a log I can see that faceCategories still contains the right number of objects
    /////////////////////////////
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.faceCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    [faceCategories release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Although my memory management skills are basic, I can't see anything particularly wrong with this, so I'd appreciate a fresh set of eyes if anyone would be so kind? I find it particularly odd that it only manifests itself when I go back to the root view controller a couple of times.

Full source - http://pastebin.com/5XzwN0bA

Comment: your code is kinda badly formatted (dealloc in the middle of that code block for example).  Can you clean up?  Also, you do `if (self.faceCategories == nil)` checks everywhere else, why don't you do that same check in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: My mistake - happened when i copied and edited the text.

Comment: I did try adding in an if but it passes the condition fine, then fails when setting the cell text.

Comment: one last thing to try... we'll break your problem into two pieces.  Can you do `NSString * textToSet = [self.faceCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` and then `cell.textLabel.text = textToSet;` right after that and step through those two pieces and tell me where the EXEC_BAD_ACCESS happens?

Comment: In this line you have leak now `self.faceCategories = ...`

Comment: the bad access occurs at `cell.textLabel.text = textToSet;`

Comment: @beryllium when allocating the self.faceCategories? that is released during dealloc

Comment: No. Your property will retain new created array as well. +1 reference vith `alloc` when you setting the property

Comment: @squarefrog, release in dealloc relates to retain in .h file where you declared a property.

Comment: OK - but I don't really know where I can release it, as I use the array throughout my RootViewController. So don't `alloc` synthesized properties?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5344/discussion-between-squarefrog-and-beryllium)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not exactly a fix, I found that the easiest way to get rid of these errors was to enable ARC. To do this go to Edit > Refactor > Convert to Objective-C ARC.

Have a read of the various ARC blog posts, but doing this means I get to forget about memory management completely, and concentrate on new features.

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying the three lines after: `// Zombies percentages after`
 with:

```
NSMutableArray *fileContents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
self.faceCategories = fileContents;
[fileContents release];
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the source above. But you're not pasting all of your code. Post the rest of this class, and also tell us what connections you have made in the xib file relating to this view controller.

Comment: You could be retaining the faceCategories array some where else paste your entire rootviewcontroller code to help you find the problem.

Comment: Actually I could not find any other errors with the source provided, try to do comment some lines and check to see if the leak has gone, and repeat this operation until you got it gone. and as for the EXC_BAD_ACCESS you can add the Environment variable NSZombie setting it to YES helps me very much avoiding such problems.